# How to make kdialog --radiolist accept list parameters from a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, kde-plasma, kdialog

With the following I get a nice dialog with quoted texts and the third preselected:

```
kdialog --title 'Snapshot status' --radiolist 'Select the desired snapshot status' production "production description" off alpha "alpha description" off beta "beta description" on release "release description" off
```

With the following I expected the same

```
radiolist='production "production description" off alpha "alpha description" off beta "beta description" on release "release description" off'
kdialog --title 'Snapshot status' --radiolist 'Select the desired snapshot status' $radiolist
```

But instead I get the following broken list with the fourth (**description"**) selected:

```
"production
alpha
off
description"
"release
```

When I accept the default it return **"beta**.  When fed from a variable it apparently does not respect the quotes and only sees single words. It works with single words items without quotes only. So when I want an item phrase then I will need to hardcode them and they cannot come from a variable. Even with the whole command line in a variable the same will happen. Do you consider this a bug or is it a feature? How to solve or work around this? is this a bash limitation or issue?

Some might ask why I would like to feed the list parameters through a variable? Well with my code I would like conditionally to change the default **on** status to an other list item.

Comment: Use an array. `radiolist=(production "production description" off alpha "alpha description" off beta "beta description" on release "release description" off) ; kdialog --title 'Snapshot status' --radiolist 'Select the desired snapshot status' "${radiolist[@]}"`

Comment: See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for an explanation.

Comment: So it is a Bash feature, not a bug? Now I'll have to learn how to build the array in stead of working with a string.

Comment: It's how bash parses command lines. Syntax parsing, like quotes, happens before parameter expansion so if you try to embed quotes in a variable then they'll be treated as literal characters instead of bash syntax. Once you ram all the arguments into a single string there isn't really a safe way to maintain boundaries between each argument anymore, which is why arrays are standard practice for this use case. Arrays can keep a list of strings and maintain boundaries between them.